# What permission is needed to enable PowerShell Remoting?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am trying to enable PowerShell Remoting on my desktop where I am an Administrator.  I have setup Powershell Remoting on my laptop and it works (going from my laptop to a remote server).  On my desktop I am getting "Access is denied." I tried PowerShell as Administrator in 32 and 64 bit.  I am using Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

[image]

Comment: So you're saying that you can access it with your laptop but not desktop? and that both laptop and desktop have the same setting?

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem:
http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2009/12/28/enable-powershell-remoting-while-running-vmware-workstation-in-a-domain/

My VMWare networks were using Public profiles.

I had to be logged in as a domain user to see the error:

```
WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network connection types on this machine is set to Public
```